# Listing instances of a Model in Backbone application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, model

In my Backbone application I have a Model. Is there a way of getting all instances of this Model in the app if not all of the instances belong to same Collection? Some of the instances might not belong to any Collection at all.

**WHY** do I need to do this?

I have a namespaced models (let's say Order.Models.Entry). This is the model of the instances I am talking about. There are some collections like Order.Models.Entries that contain instances of Order.Models.Entry type. But instances get to this collection only when they are selected (with a certain attribute). Before being selected the models are just… well… models.

**UPDATE**

Obviously I could load every model I create to some `allModels` collection as it has been suggested in the comments. But the question is not really about a workaround but about exact lookup. The reason why I would like to avoid adding models to an uber-collection is that most of the models will be added to different collections anyway and I just wanted to avoid creating dummy collection for just tracking purpose.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What is the underlying problem that you think keeping track of all the models will solve?

Comment: when adding a model instance, could you always add it to an `allModels` Collection?

Comment: @KyleR I have updated the question with some more info.

Comment: just saw that. i'm thinking there's not another way. Just as there's no way in javascript to get 'all integer variables' without putting them into some sort of list or collection, I don't think you can simply get all Model instances.

Comment: @muistooshort I have added the usecase I have for the question.

Comment: When are those entry enter this selection, upon what circumstances?

Comment: You mean when do `Order.Models.Entry` instances get to `Order.Models.Entries` collection? It happens when `selected` attribute of `Order.Models.Entry` becomes `true` (is triggered through a View).  There is only one instance of `Order.Models.Entries` (kind of an order summary).

Comment: Why don't you have the View add `Order.Models.Entry` to the `Order.Models.Entries` upon selection?

Comment: @ekeren that's exactly what I am doing. But I need to be able to choose models that are not in `Order.Models.Entries` yet. So those are not added to any collection at all yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are a couple of good design reasons why you shouldn't be doing it. (encapsulation, not polluting the global scope, etc...)

If you still wish to have this solution you could just maintain a Gloabl list and have your Backbone.Model insert itself into this list, here is a quick solution:

```
var allMyModels = [] ;

var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   initialize:function(){
       allMyModels.push(this);
       // Some more code here
    },
     // also if you wish you need to remove self on close delete function
});
var x = new MyModel();
var y = new MyModel();
```

in the end of this code, allMyModels will have both models

Comment: But now they're in `allMyModels` forever.

Comment: Again, upvoting for the workaround. But also accepting the 'No' answer.Thanks.

Comment: @muistooshort you don't mean it's bad, do you? I mean in my particular case it's fine – these models live for a certain period while user is making an order. Once the order is done or cancelled, the collection will be killed and all models destroyed.

Comment: @spliter: But `allMyModels` isn't a collection, it is just an array that holds references to model instances that no one else will be referencing. Since nothing cleans up `allMyModels`, it will just grow and collection cruft until the whole page gets replaced from the server.

Comment: Ah! You are totally right @muistooshort didn't even notice this! This makes this answer not really acceptable then. Having `allModels` as a Collection would be much smarter for performance reasons.

Comment: I accept this answer and the workaround but in order to "not polluting the global scope" `allMyModels` will be a namespaced collection. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a Collection (we'll call it `allModels`) and each time a model is created, do: `allModels.add(model)`. That way, you can access the models, and if you destroy one it will remove itself from the collection.